# Error on thr page jQuery(...).on is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii

I am creating my first yii framework project. I am using cgridview in my project. When I load the page an error is showing in the console. The error is coming from a Javascript code generated by cgridview. 
error is

```
TypeError: jQuery(...).on is not a function


jQuery(document).on('click','#items-grid a.delete',function(){
```

My javascript is

```
/*<![CDATA[*/
jQuery(function($) {
jQuery(document).on('click','#items-grid a.delete',function(){
                                confirmDelete(this);
                                return false;
                            });
jQuery('#items-grid').yiiGridView({'ajaxUpdate':['menuitems-    grid'],'ajaxVar':'ajax','pagerClass':'pager','loadingClass':'grid-view-loading','filterClass':'filters','tableClass':'items','selectableRows':1,'enableHistory':false,'updateSelector':'{page}, {sort}','filterSelector':'{filter}','pageVar':'items_page'});
});
/*]]>*/
```

What Kind of issue this is. I have included jquery.js latest vertion in my header. I tried older version also but this error is same. How should I fix this error?

Comment: which version of jQuery are you exactly using ?

Comment: There is a good change you have a conflict. Or a separate component is loading a different jQuery version on top of the one you included.

Comment: Yes, I fixed it by removing one jquery file from my page.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to disable Yii's build-in JQuery and use your own version of JQuery. To disable Yii's built-in JQuery put the following lines into your view and load your own JQuery with avoiding conflicts:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->scriptMap=array(
    'jquery.js'=>false,
    'jquery.ui.js' => false,
);
```